# Does the meaning of the assignment statement in the declaration of a reference is different then after it?

Tags: c++, reference

For example:

```
int a = 0;
int& ref = a;
```

In this example it took a and add it another name - "ref", and they are the same place at the memory.
In this example:

```
int a = 0;
int& ref = a;
ref = 5;
```

it replaced the value of a (so that it replaced "also" the value of ref).
So now the assignment statement gets a new meaning?

Comment: There is only one assignment there – `ref = 5;`. The other four lines are initialisations.

Comment: So the meaning in the initialisations are different than the assignment?

Comment: Yes, an assignment is not the same thing as an initialisation. Initialisation is creation, assignment is modification. (There is nothing similar to C++ references in Python, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

When the referent is initialized, it binds itself to an object.

After, you are modifying the bound object, not the reference.

Think of the reference as a pointer you cannot modify once created (but that always points to a valid object, no null reference possible).

Comment: int x = 5;  int& ref = x;  int y = x; So when i initalize a reference (like in this example), "x" gets other meaning just than the value in it (like the assignment to "y")?

Comment: No, `x` will always be `x`. But if you access `ref`, it will return or set the value of `x`. Like a pointer to `x` would do. It's not like in Python where all variables point to objects. Here, `x` is the int itself, not a pointer to it

Comment: So if "x" represents only the value in it, how the referece know who (which address in the memory) to bind itself to?

Comment: No, `x` is an int. It's the object itself, it doesn't represent, it is.

Comment: ok, so the initialization or the assignment takes whats it need from "x" depend on the type of what it want?

Comment: It takes the address of the object and that's it. If the types don't match, then you may have a problem.

Comment: So why don't we put there &x? And dude, thanks for the patience

Comment: Because &x takes the address of x, creating a pointer, not a reference (they are different because you can change where a pointer points to, it's not the case for a reference which has to point to a valid object).

Answer (score 1):

The `=` in the **definition** of an object is **not an assignment**; it's an **initialization**. And, yes, the meaning of an initialization is not the same as the meaning of an assignment.

```
int a = 0;    // initialize a to 0
int& ref = a; // initialize ref to refer to a
ref = 5;      // assign 5 to ref; ref is a reference, so this assigns 5 to a
```

**Initialization** refers to creating an object (in the example code, an `int` and an `int&`; the `=` sign in an initialization tells the compiler what to use as the initial value of that object.

**Assignment** refers to setting a new value to an already existing object. So `int a = 0;` is initialization; `a = 3;` is assignment.

Comment: I think that i I didn't explain myself properly. Now my question is why a reference in his initialization gets (in this example) "a" and not "&a"? (beacuse it needs to know which address to bind to in the memory)

Comment: @Python Because the binding is saying "'ref' means the same thing as 'a'", not "'ref' is the address of 'a'". After the binding, "ref" and "a" are synonyms. References are not pointers, and don't necessarily have any physical representation at all. (The ampersand, `&`, has three distinct meanings in C++. Don't confuse them.)

Comment: @Python — a reference refers to an object so it gets initialized with that object. A **pointer** points at an object, so it gets initialized with the address of that object: `int*ip = &a;`.

Comment: what do you mean by the word "object"?

Comment: @Python -- good question! I use the term in the way that the C++ language definition uses it, and that's different from "object in "object-oriented programming". An object is anything that has data and operations. `int a;` makes `a` an object; `std::cout` is an object; `std::vector<int> vec;` makes `vec` an object. A reference is not an object; it has no operations that belong to it, just the operations that apply to the object that it refers to.